# Is broadcast intent broadcasted when the application is launched?

Tags: android

Is the broadcast receiver started when the application is started or do you have to call it in the onCreate of your activity?

Answer (score 0):

It is not. You need to call `registerReceiver()` to start the receiver.

Also, it depends on what your receiver does in respect to your application. If your receiver makes sense only within a specific Activity, then call `registerReceiver()`. If it's something that, say, looks for intents broadcasted from the system (like intents signaling that the OS has booted up), then you should declare your receiver in the manifest file as follows:

```
<receiver android:name=".NameOfReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="INTENT_NAME" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```